# Ember nested routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a model plant and a related model planting which should have urls like:

```
/plants
/plants/new
/plants/some-plant-id/planting/new
```

The route to add planting works in url and displays the correct add form.  Problem is the submit with action on planting/new does not work.

Console

```
ember.debug.js:19699 Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'savePlanting'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

I am guessing the issue is with the way I constructed the route in router.js but not sure.  There is only one controller-  app/controllers/application.js which is minimal

Here is some of my code

app/routes/planting/new.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {    
    return this.store.createRecord('planting');
  },

  actions: {

    savePlanting(newPlanting) {
      console.log("trying to save...");
      newPlanting.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('planting'));
    },

    willTransition() {
       //rollbackAttributes() removes the record from the store
       //if the model 'isNew'
      this.controller.get('model').rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
});
```

router.js

```
...
this.route('plants', function() {
  this.route('new');
  this.route('edit', { path: '/:plant_id/edit' });

  this.route('planting',  { path: '/plants/:plant_id/planting' },   function(){
    this.route('new');
  });

});
...
```

Incidentally, my template directories are like

```
app/templates/plants
app/templates/plants/new.hbs
app/templates/plants/planting/new.hbs  //plantings dir in plants
```

routes directories are

```
app/routes/plants
app/routes/planting
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just put {{this}} in your templates to see which controller it´s trying to use, furthermore install ember inspector so you can see better debug routes templates and controllers, you´ll see necessary naming conventions etc. and it´s easier to understand what and where ember expects things.

Ember always bubbles actions from controller -> route if you´re not preventing it, if the error occurs the action can´t be found in either of those.

Comment: adding {{this}} to template gives me (generated plants.planting.new controller) which makes sense from what you said about controllers bubbling to route.  Since I have not created controller for plant or planting, what do I do?  create controllers?  start using components?  if I create controller, where would I put controller file that contains the savePlanting action given this dot notation?

Comment: the generated shows it´s using the controller for plants/planting/new so the action should be in the matching route it gets more clear if you would have named ...plating/new differently (that would be another problem route names should be unique), so "app/routes/planting/new.js" should be app/routes/plants/plating/new, check ember console if the path shown "generated route" so you know if the file is missing or needs to be generated, it´s a low easier if you generate them by command line btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you want to use action from your `route` in template.

In order to do so you should use `route-action` helper (https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper).

Otherwise it will look for an action in controller :)

Comment: saving the plant in plants route works just fine.  I am just learning ember and I am guessing that this should be a component in the future anyway.  I created a planting controller file and added the action to it and get the same error, so I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: I think it would be the best if you could prepare simple yet in this example "not working" demo on https://ember-twiddle.com so that we can investigate it without guessing. I think there might be a problem with directories structure. Btw. Shouldn't your routes dir look like this: ?
{ plants.js, plants: { planting.js, planting: { new.js } } }

Answer (score 1):

If you see the ajax request for saving the new planting go out to the backend, it could also be that somehow the action is then bubbled up (that's what the second part of the error message refers to).

One thing you should do is return the promise in the action handler `newPlanting.save()` and see if that changes something. Also, please show us the template where the action is fired from.

Comment: there is no ajax request...action containig newPlanting.save is not found

Comment: Indeed, I did not read that carefully. Seeing the template where the action is fired from would still be valuable to be able to help you.